# Connect to remote database available under VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, mariadb-10.3

I have a server available at AWS and the client is asking to connect to their MariaDB database remotely which is available on their server that is accessible via VPN.

---

So, how is it possible to connect to a remote database from the web application hosted on my AWS server?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You establish VPN between your VPC at AWS with your client network.

Comment: You might not have to establish a VPN between the VPC to client AWS, the client might not allow that. Rather you can use a package like OpenVPN and connect to your clients' VPN from your EC2. You can then access the DB directly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :)